# Increasing RF to 3 from 1 Causes Data Misses

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Using DSE with SOLR, we increased our RF from 1 to 3.  We immediately noticed that SOLR queries were resulting in data misses consistent with the 1:3 ratio.  Is there something special we need to do in order to increase the RF from 1 to 3 using DSE 3.1.3 with SOLR.

**Edit:**
I'm aware that a repair should be run to get data on other nodes and we were in in the process of running the repair. <strike>There still, however, shouldn't be any blank results served up as this is what bloom filters were intended for.</strike>

I seem to have been mistaken about the use of the bloom filter. It seems that I must increase the CL to `ALL` before upping the RF and drop it back down after the repairs have completed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the cluster already has data in it, you need to run a `nodetool repair` for each node to force the data to be rebalanced to match the new RF.

Comment: I'm aware that re should be running a repair, but in the meantime this causes the flapping of data retrieval?   I haven't seen this happen in the past when increasing the rf.  As I understand it, the bloom filters are supposed to prevent this.

Comment: It depends on your consistency level. If you increase RF from 1 to 3 and read at CL.QUORUM, then if Cassandra chooses the two nodes that don't have the data you will get an empty result back. The only safe CL for this RF increase is CL.ALL until repair has completed. Bloom filters don't help with this, they are just for determining which local SSTables contain a given key.

Comment: I see, i must have gotten lucky in the past then.  Can you update your answer to include reading at `ALL`

Answer (score 5):

Bloom filters are used in Cassandra to efficiently access on-disk data, they have nothing to do with Solr distributed queries.

The reason why you're seeing less data than expected is that your cluster metadata, more specifically token/replica assignments, changed, but actual data didn't relocate yet because of the pending repair: hence, Solr is using the updated cluster metadata to properly run a distributed query, taking into account the new RF, but the actual data isn't there to be retrieved yet.